# Is this a bug in Visual Studio with modules?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Make a module file:

```
export module MyModule;
#include <iostream>
```

Then in main.cpp (not a module):

```
import MyModule;
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling in either debug or release I get the errors:

> Error C2365   '__ISA_AVAILABLE_X86': redefinition; previous definition
> was 'enumerator'
>
> Error C2365   'std::denorm_indeterminate': redefinition; previous
> definition was 'enumerator'

If I comment out one of the includes it compiles fine. My version of Visual Studio is Version 17.7.6.

Comment: My module-fu is weak, but I don't think you're supposed to `#include` inside modules like this. You can do it in a [global module fragment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) (`module;` first, then include, then `export module MyModule;` and the rest of the code).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So there is module; module MyModule; and export module MyModule;? I can't get this. BTW that worked, include before export module MyModule; didn't need 'module' at the top, whatever that does.

Comment: It is a known limitation that MSVC will believe that things imported belongs to that module, and trying to also `#include` the same header will be seen as a duplicate.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem in this thread? The new thread has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

##### Modules, top to bottom

With Visual Studio, if you set the C++ Language Standard to

> Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)

You can use `import std`, and just forget about needing to `#include` almost all Standard Library headers. Try it. It's addictive!

In addition, I usually use a module for function `main`, as well as everything else in a modules project.

```cpp
// main.ixx
export module main;
import std;
import MyModule;

export int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.ixx
```

```cpp
// MyModule.ixx
export module MyModule;
import std;

export
{
    std::string foo()
    {
        return "Hello, modules!";
    }
}
// end file: MyModule.ixx
```

Output:

```
Hello, modules!
```

In an [article on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170), Microsoft reports that importing the entire Standard Library (which is what `import std` and `import std.compat` do) results in:

> significantly faster compilation and is more robust than using header files or header units or precompiled headers (PCH).

That has generally been my experience, as well.

So, `import std` is the future. Importing the entire Standard Library results in better compile times than importing or including individual headers. No more hassle with stopping as you code, and scrolling to the top, just so you can add another `#include`. Good riddance to all of that!

For now, however, Microsoft has included `import std` as a "preview feature," saying:

> The feature is subject to change between preview releases. You shouldn't use preview features in production code.

##### Header units are the next best thing

If you decide not to use `import std`, you can still import the headers from the Standard Library. This converts them into *header units*. For example, you can use `import <vector>;` instead of `#include <vector>`.

CppReference describes header units on its [Modules page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules#Importing_modules_and_header_units):

> A header unit is a separate translation unit synthesized from a header. Importing a header unit will make accessible all its definitions and declarations. Preprocessor macros are also accessible (because import declarations are recognized by the preprocessor).
>
> However, contrary to #include, preprocessing macros already defined at the point of the import declaration will not affect the processing of the header. This may be inconvenient in some cases (some headers use preprocessing macros as a form of configuration), in which case the usage of global module fragment is needed.

Header units are not preview feature. Presumably, then, you can use them in production code. [Microsoft's advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170) is:

> In some cases, you can import a header file as a module, which is faster than using #include to process it with the preprocessor. We recommend that you use modules in new projects rather than header files as much as possible. For larger existing projects under active development, experiment with converting legacy headers to modules. Base your adoption on whether you get a meaningful reduction in compilation times.

Note that the article where this quote appears is mostly obsolete. It describes how to use an early, experimental version of modules, which are compiled with the `/experimental:module` compiler switch. Don't do that! Instead, just set the C++ Language Standard to:

> ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)

The example program from above then becomes:

```cpp
// main.cpp
export module main;
import <iostream>;  // imports a "header unit"
import MyModule;    // imports a module

export int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

```cpp
// MyModule.ixx
export module MyModule;
import <string>;  // imports a "header unit"

export
{
    std::string foo()
    {
        return "Hello, modules!";
    }
}
// end file: MyModule.ixx
```

##### Mixing the old with the new

Otherwise, the advice given by @HolyBlackCat is spot-on. When you are forced to use `#include`, it belongs in the *global module fragment*.

In this example, `main.cpp` is not a module, and `MyModule` uses the global module fragment.

```cpp
// main.cpp

// You can mix `import` and `#include` in the same translation unit.
#include <iostream>
import MyModule;

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

```cpp
// MyModule.ixx

// The global module fragment begins here, with the `module;` statement.
module;
#include <string>

// The global module fragment ends when an `export module` 
// declaration is encountered.
export module MyModule;  

// This is an "export block". 
// All names declared within an export block are exported.
export
{
    std::string foo()
    {
        return "Hello, modules!";
    }
}
// end file: MyModule.ixx
```

Comment: I'm excited about modules but a lot of the stuff I read has got me pessimistic. I was just reading on the cpp subreddit seeing how awful some things were. You haven't had problems with support and quirks? Do you use only MSVC? How about Clang and GCC?

Comment: All my experience has been with MSVC. In general, I have had good success, with no problems at all in projects that use `import std` exclusively. I have heard, however, that GCC is lagging, and Clang, as well, but perhaps to a lesser extent. But those are just rumors to me. Most of the problems I hear about have to do with integrating third-party libraries that are not modules-aware. Programs that depend on macros do not always play well well with modules.

Comment: Just ran into this problem, I made a question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77590939/cannot-find-stdpartial-ordering-please-include-compare-header . This stuff is unusable it's so frustrating it's no wonder so many people are using Rust.